# How to make draggable item change style once dropped on the original position?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to change style of draggable image once it drops on a droppable place and change it back once it returns.

I succeeded in change it css on right drop, but now can't change it back once it's back to it's original place.

the "start" and "stop" didn't help.
I think what I need is a condition that depends on the element position, or do something with the "revert" option on the .draggable function but can't find out how and what to write.

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggableImagesQ1").draggable({

        revert: function (event, ui) {

            // on older version of jQuery use "draggable"
            // $(this).data("draggable")
            // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable"
            // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top: 0,
                left: 0 
            };

            // return boolean
            return !event;
            // that evaluate like this:
            // return event !== false ? false : true;
        }
    });
    $(".droppableSpace1").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            $("#draggableImagesQ1").addClass("afterDragged");

        }
    });
});
```

for now it changes style only when dropped on the drop zone. but not changing back when returns to original position.

The element is set to width and height of 80px. once dropped correctly, it changes to 120px. I want it to change back to 80px once dragged AND dropped in it's ORIGINAL POSITION.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect you need two drop zones. In one, it adds the class and in the other it removes the class. It may be helpful to provide a full example so we can help more. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So you mean the initial position would also be a drop zone? that way I can write a condition that checks which zone it is